# TinyMCE HTMLField and Django TextField don't show up in production

Tags: python, django

When I visit my Modelform in the admin of my localhost development server all of the fields are shown just fine. However, once I go to the admin on my web-app in production, both the `HTMLField` and `TextField` don't show any inputfields.

If it would just be the TinyMCE `HTMLField` it would be less confusing, but having the common `TextField` bugged as well is weird.

What do I miss?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    [...]
 
    # tinymce
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'width': 1200,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from tinymce import TinyMCE
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from .models import Post, Comment


class TinyMCEWidget(TinyMCE):
    def use_required_attribute(self, *args):
        return False


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Add Tiny MCE Widget to Admin Interface
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        )
    ),
    # Add DateTime Picker Widget to Admin Interface
    publish_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'overview', 'content', 'thumbnail',
        'categories', 'publish_date')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

# Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=28, blank=False)
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False)
    stock_website = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
    overview = models.TextField(max_length=140, blank=False) # doesn't show up in production
    content = HTMLField() # doesn't show up in production
    [...]
```

This is how it looks like in Production:

[image]

vs development having the very same code on each side:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a painful night, I finally got it run.

Check the following:

- TinyMCE v4.x doesn't support the `modern` theme, however, it works in development for whatever reason

So if you are on v4.x make sure to change the theme to `silver` respectively, reboot your production server and it should work just fine:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'width': 1200,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'silver', # Magic here
    [...]
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `modern` theme, you have to upgrade to v5.x

If it then still doesn't work, it is probably due to missing static files path. Go ahead and ensure that you defined it correctly like so:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tinymce/tinymce.min.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tinymce/")
```

The [official docu](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#testing) suggests the defaults for the statics files which in my case didn't match.

I still don't know why the common Django Textfield was affected as well, but it probably has something to do with the TinyMCE settings, weird.

Answer (score 0):

since the behavior seems to appear only in **production** environment, maybe be you need to re-run `collectstatic` command

```
(venev) $ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Hey, that didn't change anything